# Get appearance of slides class with sections and smaller title

Tags: beamer, article

I use OneNote as a digital white board to teach undergraduates. One of the great features is the ability to draw on top of pdfs, documents, slides, websites, anything. I have a series of notes in \LaTeX\ that I would love to use, but I want to avoid generating beamer slides because:

1. page breaks are tedious to insert and don't add much given OneNote's continuous scrolling and my teaching style
2. students add their own notes to the handouts, and I think the slide breaks are unnecessary for this use and waste paper

The `slides` class works great for this, but has two problems:

1. `slides` doesn't allow any structure and my (many) notes have `\section{}` and `\subsection{}` that I would like to keep
2. `slides` has a title page that I would like to make a header more like `article`

I thought `article` and a font change to sans serif would do the trick, but `article` only has 10-12pt fonts.

Is there a fix here? Or do I need to go wholly into beamer to get large print "articles" that I can project on a screen?

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{slides}

\author{Me}
\title{Lecture One}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% \section{One}

Here are some insigthful comments on section one.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}

% \section{Two}

Here are some insigthful comments on section two.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}

% \section{Three}

Here are some insigthful comments on section three.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}


\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}Here's an example problem \hfill\vspace{\textheight}\end{minipage}}

And a table.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
left & right \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer `pdfscreen` and `texpower` to `beamer`.  You can still use `\begin{slide}` ... `\end{slide}` but I generally don't.  Note that `\section` does not start a new page in article class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,allcolors=blue}
%\usepackage[display]{texpower}

\margins{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}
\screensize{4.5in}{6in}% for a 3x4 display
%\screensize{4.5in}{8in}% for a 9x16 widescreen display
\backgroundcolor{lightgray}
\parindent=0pt

% redefine font sizes
\let\tiny=\footnotesize
\let\scriptsize=\small
\let\footnotesize=\normalsize
\let\small=\large
\let\normalsize=\Large
\let\large=\LARGE
\let\Large=\huge
\let\LARGE=\Huge% this is as large as it gets
\let\huge=\Huge

\author{Me}
\title{Lecture One}

\begin{document}
%\begin{slide}
%\parbox{\textwidth}{\maketitle}% to vertically center \maketitle
%\end{slide}

\maketitle

\section{One}

Here are some insightful comments on section one.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}

\section{Two}

Here are some insightful comments on section two.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}

\section{Three}

Here are some insightful comments on section three.

\begin{itemize}
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
    \item blah
\end{itemize}


\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}Here's an example problem 
 \hfill\vspace{\dimexpr \textheight-\baselineskip-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}\end{minipage}}

And a table.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
left & right \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very cool. But is there a way to get larger font sizes? I will project this in a screen. I can handle sans serif fonts with `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}`, but how can I get text larger than 12pt?

Comment: I usually just add \Large after \begin{document}, but that only affects normal text (not \section, for example).  A better solution is to reduce the page size.  I mostly chose this size to make switching between 3x4 and 9x16 easy.  That and the default font size inside the slide environment is already too large.

Comment: I looked at the way base.sty redefined the font sizes for slide class and adopted their approach.  The largest font they use is still 40pt (\Huge).

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. For me, changing the font macros is a better approach than changing the paper size so that I can generate a print-out. But making the paper A6 and changing to sans serif fonts makes the notes readable on a smartphone.

Comment: In addition to the font size changes above, I add the following to the preamble. `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{cmbright}`

Comment: I also tried the relsize package, but it didn't seem to do anything.  The moresize package adds a \HUGE font if you need one.